# Why does on('data') listener interpret 2 different requests as one unless you add timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know what I'm missing here but node seems to interpret 2 different requests as a single one unless you add timeout, for example in the code below when I write to server one and two and push result to array it just combines the both strings and interprets them as one, whereas when I add a 10 ms delay then it works the way I need it to.

```
var arr = [];

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
  socket.on('data', function(data){
    arr.push(data.toString());
  });
}).listen(8080);


var connection = net.connect({host: 'localhost', port: 8080});
connection.write('one');
connection.write('two');

setTimeout(function() {
  connection.write('three')
}, 10);

setTimeout(function() {
  connection.write('four')
}, 20);

setTimeout(function() {
  connection.write('five')
}, 30);

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(arr); //[ 'onetwo', 'three', 'four', 'five' ]
}, 2000);
```

Comment: You have a global array you're pushing into... of course they're "handled the same way" you're putting the contexts of both requests in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Request" here is not correct. you don't "Request" something when you deal with sockets. sockets do not equal http requests. sockets are data source you can read and write into. there is no meaning how the data was splitted before it was sent, when the socket reads - it reads all the data which is available at the point of the reading.

if you write many buffers consecutivley into the same socket it is very possible that by the time the socket is awekened by the kernel to process the data , the data from the second write had already arrived and processed in the same read action.

when you put a 10 milliseconds timeout, you interval the read actions thus you ensure the data is splitted.